# Apache camel retry attempts to activeMQ failing with message session closed

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am working on a spring boot project. In that I am trying to resend messages to activeMQ using apache camel route. However while the retry attempts are working perfectly the message failed to deliver as session has closed.

**CamelRoute:**

```
     @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        onException(UncategorizedJmsException.class, JMSException.class, ConnectException.class)
        .maximumRedeliveries(retryCount).redeliveryDelay(redeliveryDelay).onRedelivery(retryProcessor).process(ExceptionProcessor);

        from("direct:sendMessage").to(queueName);
 }
```

queueName is defined in application.properties as
outbound.endpoint=jms:DUMMY.QUEUE

retryProcessor just prints the log messages with retry count.

While executing I am getting below error on each retry even when activemq is up.

```
2017-07-11 07:51:40.955  WARN 9912 --- []] o.a.c.c.jms.EndpointMessageListener      : Execution of JMS message listener failed. Caused by: [javax.jms.IllegalStateException - The Session is closed]

javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.checkClosed(ActiveMQSession.java:771) ~[activemq-client-5.13.4.jar:5.13.4]
at org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQSession.getTransacted(ActiveMQSession.java:540) ~[activemq-client-5.13.4.jar:5.13.4]
at org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledSession.getTransacted(PooledSession.java:260) ~[activemq-jms-pool-5.13.4.jar:5.13.4]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.rollbackOnExceptionIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:794) ~[spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:658) ~[spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:317) [spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:255) [spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1166) [spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158) [spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1055) [spring-jms-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_74]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_74]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74]
```

My JMS configuration class is:

```
    @Bean
public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
    // use a pool for ActiveMQ connections
    PooledConnectionFactory pool = new PooledConnectionFactory();
    pool.setConnectionFactory(
            new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(userName, password, "tcp://" + jmsServer + ":" + jmsPort));
    pool.setMaxConnections(maxConnections);

    return pool;
}

@Bean("activemq")
public ActiveMQComponent getActiveMQComponent() {
    // use a pool for ActiveMQ connections
    JmsConfiguration jmsConfig = new JmsConfiguration();
    jmsConfig.setConnectionFactory(getConnectionFactory());
    jmsConfig.setConcurrentConsumers(concurrentConsumers);

    ActiveMQComponent activeMqComponent = new ActiveMQComponent();
    activeMqComponent.setConfiguration(jmsConfig);

    return activeMqComponent;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How long is your redelivery delay?

Comment: @Claus Ibsen : 3 seconds

Comment: What version of Camel and ActiveMQ are you using.

Comment: Camel: 2.18.0
ActiveMQ: 5.13.4

Comment: I am also having the same problem

Comment: @Claus I have analysed the issue further. It comes only when from and to endpoint are of type jms i.e sending message from queue to queue.